# Did the threading module change in Python 3? And if so, how?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to understand the MT in Python. I found an example using `threading.Lock`. But it generated different outputs in Python 2.7 and Python 3.6, which really confused me.

Here is the code:

```
import threading
import time
import random

 class meThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
       global num
       time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
       num += 1
       print(self.name+'set num to '+str(num))

 num = 0

 threads = []
 for i in range(5):
    t = meThread()
    threads.append(t)

 for i in range(5):
    threads[i].start()

 for i in range(5):
    threads[i].join()
```

and the output in Python3.6:

```
Thread-4set num to 1
Thread-2set num to 2
Thread-1set num to 3
Thread-3set num to 4
Thread-5set num to 5
```

and the output in Python2.7:

```
Thread-1set num to 1
Thread-4set num to 2
Thread-3set num to 4
Thread-2set num to 5
Thread-5set num to 3
```

The output is always the same in 3.6, but in 2.7 it's unexpected if not using `threading.Lock`. Why? Does the python add a lock to a thread automatically in 3.6?

Comment: What's right about the first that is wrong with the second? Did you run the code with 2.6 a few times?

Comment: why are you expecting same results when you are using a random time interval to sleep for each thread. The random time interval might differ between runs, run the code in the same version of python again might provide different results

Comment: In 3.6, the output is always 1,2,3,4,5, but it could be 1,3,4,2,5 or something like that in 2.7, which is not in an ascending order. I mean the different threads can change the global varible num at the same time if not using threading.Lock, and the output should be arbitary like in 2.7. But the outputs are always the same with 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless if the threading behavior changed between version of python, without using a lock, the behavior of incrementing `num` across multiple unsynchronized threads is going to be non-deterministic at best. Even with multiple runs on the same interpreter on the same PC, it could generate different results. Because you never know when a context switch on a thread could occur.

This statement:

```
num += 1
```

Is just shorthand for something nearly equivalent to this at run time.

```
REGISTER = num            # read memory location into a local register
REGISTER = REGISTER + 1   # increment the value
num = REGISTER            # store back to memory
```

And since any thread could get preempted by another thread or get scheduled on a different core, or the print call itself could introduce weird timing issues. There's all the cache coherency issue of multiple cores. It's entirely possible something like this is happening at run time.

```
 THREAD 1: 
      REGISTER  = num          # T1 reads 0 into register

 <context switch>

 THREAD 2: 
     REGISTER = num            #T2 reads "0" into register
     REGISTER = REGISTER + 1   #T2 increments register to "1"
     num = REGISTER            #T2 copies register value back to memory

 <context switch back to thread 1, REGISTER is restored to "0" from before>
 <but the memory location for num is now 1>

 THREAD 1: 
     REGISTER = REGISTER + 1   #T1 increments register to "1"
     num = REGISTER            #T1 copy register value ("1") back to memory
```

So as above, it's very easy for two threads to have overlapping access to a variable.

You need a lock if you want consistent behavior of `num` getting incremented to 5. An easy update:

```
 lock = Lock()

 class meThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
       global num
       global lock
       time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
       # --------------------------------
       lock.acquire()
       num += 1
       tmp = num          # save value a local tmp value for the subsequent print
       lock.release()
       # --------------------------------
       print(self.name+'set num to '+str(tmp))  # print the value of what num was incremented to while in the lock, not what num is now
```

Everything you need to know is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201101025814/http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm).

Comment: Great Answer! That's what I am thinking. But with 3.6, the num will get incremented to 5 consistently even without lock.

Comment: It might *seem* to be deterministic on a certain configuration in a small isolated console application with nothing else running. But you could see some behavior differences on a different computer with a different different number of CPU cores with various loads from other applications running. Or the next iteration of Python comes out with a subtle optimization to how the byte code is generated and changes all this again. It's non-deterministic by design.

Comment: Any while there may actually be a deep technical reason why it works differently across Python 2 and 3 (e.g. different compiler optimizations, different variable caching scheme), it's not a documented behavior for the language. And the Python development team would likely never make any guarantees this couldn't change either.

Comment: The `print(...` statement should also be inside the `Lock()` or `num` copied to a local, to get _consistent behavior of num_ Output.